# Why does this Linq query return 0 for Count()?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This seems like an inconsistency, but I'm probably just missing something obvious. The base query is:

```
var events = db.tbl_special_events.Where(x => x.TimeStamp >= startDate);
```

The apparent inconsistency comes when I run the following code block:

```
int c1 = 0;
foreach (var e in events)
{
    if (e.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Tuesday") c1++;
}

int c2 = events.Where(e => e.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Tuesday").Count();
```

After that runs, c1 is 1832, but c2 is 0. What am I missing?

Comment: I assume `c++` should be `c1++`?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `c1++`?  Are you using `c` somewhere previously that sets it's value to something other than `0`?

Comment: It actually is in my code. I added the 1 when I posted. My mistake, and edited.

Comment: @Jon But bother ints are being set from the same set of data and on the same condition, so they should be equal, right? Also, I've tried making a list and adding every event that was on Tuesday to it to verify that they did actually exist, and they did.

Comment: When/where are you examining `c2`?  If you're looking at in the debugger are you looking at if _after_ that line has run?

Comment: @Jon I'm not sure where you get that idea?

Comment: @DStanley Yes, I was. See Richard Cook's answer below for the reason it didn't work.

Comment: That is confusing behaviour. Try `.ToArray()` or similar on the base query to "save" the results; you can likely only iterate through it once. On an unrelated note, you can replace `.Where(predicate).Count()` with `.Count(predicate)`.

Comment: @Ginosaji Saving it with `.ToArray()` did the trick. Also, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just wondering... If you first calculate `c2` and then `c1`, are the results the same?

Comment: @comecme Sorry for the late answer. The code I was messing with is already gone, but the "problem" should be easy enough to recreate yourself. If you have any specific questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated this test and found that it may be directly related to the DateTime function.

The query that is generated:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[User_ID], [t0].[Email], [t0].[Password], [t0].[BrandID], [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[Created], [t0].[EndDate], [t0].[AccountStatusID], [t0].[Verified], [t0].[ResetPasswordFailCount], [t0].[ResetPasswordLocked]
FROM [dbo].[User] AS [t0]
WHERE ((CONVERT(NVarChar,CONVERT(Int,(DATEPART(dw, [t0].[Created]) + (@@DATEFIRST) + 6) % 7))) = @p0) AND ([t0].[BrandID] = @p1)',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 int',@p0=N'Tuesday',@p1=3
```

Notice where @p0=N'Tuesday'

Keeping in mind that IQueryable and IEnumerable differ in that where IEnumerable represents an actual .net object, IQueryable converts your expression into an actual SQL statement used to query the database. So any values that you provide in that expression are actually sent to the database.

It is returning 0 results because there is no match. Reason being, the date conversion in SQL returns a 2 instead of 'Tuesday'. You can test this if you replace Tuesday with 2 in your LINQ WHERE clause, it'll actually work. This will work after enumerating it since the results will have been successfully mapped into a usable .net object where the DateTime.DayOfWeek conversion to "Tuesday" will work properly.

Comment: `Count` iterates the sequence/queryable, thus executing the query at that point.  Adding a `ToList` wouldn't do anything [productive].

Comment: I was going to revise to comment about this actually. When I encountered this problem before, I had the same assumption. Adding ToList() fixed it /shrug

Comment: To your edit, that doesn't explain why his code is acting as it is.  It should either throw an exception or implicity convert the query to a LINQ to objects query and work just fine, while also executing two queries.  Since he's just doing the same thing twice it's not like it's real production code, it's merely inquiring why the two operations that seem like they should be identical are different.

Comment: The down-vote is uncalled for. Read the comments on the OP and tell me what he found as the "solution".

Comment: The explanation is incorrect, so I consider a downvote completely called for.  You have no idea why it's not working.  Clearly the OP can get the true count as evidenced by his first option; he doesn't need code that makes it work, he's asking why it doesn't work.  Your don't (correctly) answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Your count is acting on an `IQueryable<Event>` while `e` is an enumerated instance. Therefore, some operations might not work as they cannot be translated into SQL [**Edit**: or will be translated in nonsensical SQL].

To ensure your `Where` clause works add an `AsEnumerable()` before it. This converts the `IQueryable<Event>` into an `IEnumerable<Event>` and tells the linq provider that it should stop generating SQL at this point.

So, this statement should provide the correct result:

```
int c2 = events.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(e => e.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Tuesday")
    .Count();
```

The actual code that <strike>cannot be converted</strike> causes the problem in SQL is `e.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek.ToString()`.

Alternatively you can use the `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions` ([doc here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466169.aspx)) class to hint the linq provider what it should be doing in SQL.

**Edit**

<strike>As @Servy pointed out this is a Linq to SQL question. However, the problem is quite common so I leave the answer and do not delete it.</strike>

On looking at the OP again, there could be another variable to the whole game ... lazy loading.

In the foreach loop the TimeStamp is lazy loaded. In the  count query the provider tries to construct an SQL query, during this construction it might not be able to work with `ToString` (which is known to be problematic) and evaluate `e.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek.ToString()` to something different than `"Tuesday"`.

The `AsEnumerable()` forces the provider to stop generating SQL, so that `e.TimeStamp` is lazy loaded again.

The only way kowing exactly what is going on, is to use tracing tool on the DB (e.g. SQL Server Profiler) to actually see the query (or queries) executed on the server.

**Edit 2**

Building on [@Sinaesthetic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15122183/266919) the reason why 0 is returned is that the Query tries to compare `"4"` to `"Tuesday"` which returns false and therefore the correct result is `false`.

Can be tested by executing

```
select ((CONVERT(NVarChar,CONVERT(Int,(DATEPART(dw, getdate()) + (@@DATEFIRST) + 6) % 7))))
```

against the DB.

However, this also shows that it is up to the provider to decide what SQL it generates. Also it is up to the provider to decide what statements it supports and which statements it doesn't.

It also shows that ***using `AsEnumerable` to stop the SQL generation process can have an infulence on the semantic evaluation of a query***.

Comment: Wouldn't that result in an exception, not a count of zero?

Comment: Right, that's what you get often ... but not here as it's Linq to SQL and the types are mapped more directly (did not read that tag ... :-o ). However, in EF this is a common problem, so I decided not to delete the answer.

Comment: Regardless of the query provider, I've only ever seen two behaviors when a given operation couldn't be converted by the query provider; either it throws an exception, or it converts the input sequence to an `IEnumerable` and does the operation in memory.  Why would it just silently return no results, it makes no sense?

Comment: Again, fail to see how that would result in an empty collection; it seems like that ought to throw an exception.

Comment: Yes it ought to. But it depends on the provider what it does in such a case (if I am corrrect EF, for example, **will** throw an error in this case. However, the above statements regarding lazy loading and the impact on the evaluation of queries, as well as the recommendation for using `AsEnumerable` to prevent these side effects hold true.

Comment: I really wish I could give you guys more info. If you're still curious, is there anything in particular you'd like me to try to help you figure out what was going on?

Comment: @WestonOdom the explanation is in the SQL above, as well as in the description I've provided. Basically it boils down to that the SQL compares an integer converted to a string with "Tuesdday" and this always will return false. In your loop you do not run in to this problem, as `DayOfWeek` is an `enum` and that using `ToString` on an enum returns the name of the entry and not it's numerical value. Can I help you any further?

Comment: @Obalix Nope, I've got it. Thanks.